# How to remove a tag (with content) with custom class in Python Regex?

Tags: python, regex

I've figured out how to strip a tags by using regex by using:

```
text = re.sub('<body>.*?</body>', '', html)
```

However, I don't know how to use it to remove a tag with custom class, and the content inside, for example:

```
<div class="abcd">content</div><p>Helllo</p><div class="bcda">another content</div>
```

And here is the expected result

```
<p>Helllo</p>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: the short answer is: DON"T. XML parsing is tricky, and it is always better to use library. Look at `xml` [standard module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html#) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression like this.

```
text = re.sub('<div class=.*?>.*?</div>', '', html)
```